# Loop dentro de loop While PYTHON

Tags: python, loop, while

Estou a fazer um programa que sorteie um número de 0 a 5 e o usuário deve adivinhar qual é, mas ele apenas tem 3 tentativas. No caso das 3 tentativas acabarem e o usuário não adivinhar qual é o número, então iria mostrar um uma mensagem dizendo que ultrapassou o número de tentativas e se queria sair ou continuar a jogar, o problema é que come tenho um loop dentro do outro se o usuário digitar "mais" o "continue" assume que quero retornar o input dizendo que tentou vezes de mais e não o código inteiro:

```py
import random
import time
from sys import exit
print('-------------------')
print('JOGO DA ADIVINHAÇÃO')
print('-------------------')
time.sleep(2)
print('Vou pensar num número de 0 a 5...')
time. sleep(1)
tentativa=3
num=random.randint(0, 5)
while True:
 n= int(input('Tente adivinhar qual é: '))
 if tentativa >0:
        if num==n:
            print('Você ACERTOU! PARABÉNS!')
            break
        elif num!=n:
                n2=input(f'Você errou, tem {tentativa}...')
                tentativa=tentativa-1
                continue
 elif tentativa==0:
        while True:
         se=input('Você tentou vezes demais e não acertou digite "mais" para jogar novamente ou "sair" para acabar o jogo: ')
         if se=='sair':
             exit()
         elif se=='mais':
             continue
         elif se!='mais' or se!= 'sair':
             print('Não percebi o que quis dizer...')
             time.sleep(2)
             continue
```

Como faço para o código todo recomeçar?

Answer (score 1):

É só uma questão de simplificação do problema. Você tem pouco código que faz muita coisa, então será melhor separar as responsabilidades.

Você pode criar uma função que lê a tentativa do usuário:

```py
def ler_tentativa() -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input('Tente advinhar o número: '))
        except ValueError:
            print('Erro! Informe um valor inteiro')
```

Você pode criar uma função que solicite ao usuário se ele quer continuar jogando:

```py
def tentar_de_novo() -> bool:
    while True:
        answer = input('Digite "mais" para tentar novamente ou "sair" para encerrar')
        if answer not in {'sair', 'mais'}:
            print('Erro! Não entendi o que quis dizer')
            continue
        return answer == 'mais'
```

E, assim, você cria um laço que dure enquanto houver tentativas e quando encerrá-las e o usuário pedir para jogar novamente basta você aumentar para 3 o número de tentativas:

```py
tentativas = 3
sorteado = 5

while tentativas > 0:
    tentativas -= 1
    tentativa: int = ler_tentativa()

    if tentativa == sorteado:
        print('Parabéns')
        break

    if tentativas == 0 and tentar_de_novo():
        tentativas = 3
else:
    print('Fim')
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar uma variavel "auxiliar" para isto e colocar a parte de atribuição de tentativa e de um novo número dentro do Loop, desta forma:

```
import random
import time
from sys import exit
print('-------------------')
print('JOGO DA ADIVINHAÇÃO')
print('-------------------')
time.sleep(2)

inicio = True
while True:

    if(inicio): 
        print('Vou pensar num número de 0 a 5...')
        tentativa=3
        num=random.randint(0, 5)
        time. sleep(1)
        n= int(input('Tente adivinhar qual é: '))
        inicio = False

    if tentativa >0:
        if num==n:
            print('Você ACERTOU! PARABÉNS!')
            break
        elif num!=n:
            n2=input(f'Você errou, tem {tentativa}...')
            tentativa=tentativa-1
            continue

    elif tentativa==0:
        while True:
            se=input('Você tentou vezes demais e não acertou digite "mais" para jogar novamente ou "sair" para acabar o jogo: ')
            if se=='sair':
                 exit()
            elif se=='mais':
                inicio = True
                break
            elif se!='mais' or se!= 'sair':
                print('Não percebi o que quis dizer...')
                time.sleep(2)
                continue
```

Entretanto o código está um pouco verboso, e aparentemente com algumas mensagens que poderá ocasionar problema.

Aconselho a dar uma estudada em funções para tornar o seu código menos verboso, conforme alguns já mencionaram nas respostas.